# Как заставить квадрат двигаться

Tags: javascript, html

подскажите что не так, почему квадрат который должен двигаться, делает это со скоростью черепахи, даже тише и добравшись до верха странице, там встаёт
вот код:

javascript:

```
var vx;
var vy;
var flag;
function init()
{
flag=false;
lay.style.backgroundColor="orange";
lay.style.top=Math.round((Math.random()*450));
lay.style.left=Math.round((Math.random()*750));
vx=Math.round((Math.random()*10))-5;
vy=Math.round((Math.random()*10))-5;
move();
}

function move()
{
if(flag==true){return}
var x=lay.style.left;
var y=lay.style.top;
if(Math.round((Math.random()*1000))<10)
{
    vx=Math.round((Math.random()*10))-5;
    vy=Math.round((Math.random()*10))-5;
}
x=parseInt(x)+vx;
y=parseInt(y)+vy;
if(x<=0)
{
    x=0;
    vx=-vx;
}

if(x>=750)
{
    x=750;
    vx=-vx;
}

if(y<=0)
{
    y=0;
    vy=-vy;
}

if(y>=450)
{
    y=450;
    vy=-vy;
}

lay.style.left=x;
lay.style.top=y;
setTimeout("move();",30);
}

function vis()
{
document.forms[0].Yes.value++;
flag=true;
lay.style.backgroundColor="red";
setTimeout("init();",400);
}
```

html:

```
<body onLoad="init()">

<div id="field" onClick="javascript:document.forms[0].No.value++;">

</div>

<div id="lay" onClick="vis()"></div>

<div id="control">

<form>

<h2>Счёт</h2>

попал:<br>

<input id="Yes"><br>

мимо<br>

<input id="No">

</form>

</div>

</body>
```

подскажите, где в этом коде ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите консоль на наличие JS ошибок.

В данном случае, еще не определив до конца ф-ю `move()`, вы уже пытаетесь использовать ссылку на нее в ней же, в `setTimeout("move();",30);`

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/UDqp5/)

Comment: `move` определена как `function move` поэтому ее можно использовать даже _до_ того как написана строчка `function move`